# Conveying "Don't air your dirty laundry in public"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, grec

What are some French idioms that convey the following idiom?

"Don't air your dirty laundry in public"

(meaning private matters should remain so; don't reveal secrets to the public)

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/air_one%27s_dirty_laundry_in_public

(or even better the Greek idiom τα εν οίκω μη εν δήμω [ta en ˈiko mi en ˈðimo]

https://www.wordsense.eu/%CF%84%CE%B1_%CE%B5%CE%BD_%CE%BF%CE%AF%CE%BA%CF%89_%CE%BC%CE%B7_%CE%B5%CE%BD_%CE%B4%CE%AE%CE%BC%CF%89/
)

Comment: https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/Don't%20air%20one's%20dirty%20laundry%20in%20public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'expression consacrée est :

> Laver son linge sale en famille.

Elle indique le fait que les sombres histoires doivent être réglées en privé, sans impliquer d'autre acteurs (la presse par ex.).

"En famille" n'est pas à prendre au sens propre, car il peut s'agir aussi d'un entreprise ou d'une autre entité (club, association, etc.).

voir par exemple [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/laver_son_linge_sale_en_famille) :

> L’armée, l’aurait-il oublié, est un milieu clos où l’on a l’habitude de **laver son linge sale en famille**

Comment: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/laver_son_linge_sale_en_public

Comment: @None Oui merci, ça marche aussi dans ce sens là. J'ai proposer l'inverse car la demande était plutôt *ne pas laver son linge sale en public*.